# How to get group id of sliding windows but only after completion of earliest started window

Tags: r, rolling-computation

Let me be straightforward in telling that it may be a bit complicated for me to explain.

Let's assume that I have a vector with run-lengths of (forward) sliding window sizes.

```
xx <- c(3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L)
xx
[1] 3 2 1 4 4 3 3 1 2 1 2 3 4 3 2 1
```

- First element is 3, which means window size (forward) for it, is of length 3.  And so on.
- I want to assign first three (because 1st element is 3) elements a same group no. say 1
- Now I want to leave 2nd and 3rd elements - because they subsumed in first window and therefore these elements be allocated same group no. i.e. 1
- Pick 4th element then, it s window size is 4.  Then allocate next four elements (including this one) another group no. say 2.
- Now pick 8th element (3+4 have been completed).  and allocate unique group no say 3 to element count of its size which is 1 only.
- Next pick 9th element and so on.
- It is assured that last group will automatically be exhausted or it'll be 1.

My desired output is as below:

```
c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` and return the *accumulated* index from which to which you jump. `as.factor` and `as.integer` is used to get numbers 1, 2, 3, ...

```
as.integer(as.factor(Reduce(function(i, j) if(i > j) i else i + xx[i+1],
 seq_len(length(xx)-1), xx[1], accumulate = TRUE)))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 6
```

Another option is to use a *recursive* function.

```
f <- function(i) {
  if(i >= length(xx)) length(xx)
  else c(i, f(i + xx[i + 1]))
}

x <- diff(f(0))
rep(seq(x), x)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 6
```

Comment: Seems fabulous.  Upvoted already.  Without `as.integer` and `as.factor` will do.  But can you please explain the logic behind the formula.  Or can it be rewritten using `purrr::accumulate` in which case, it'll be easier for me to understand

Comment: Sorry I don't know the usage of `purrr::accumulate`. It simply compares the current index with a value and if the current index is larger than the value then the value is increased with the number in `xx` at the next position.

Answer (score 2):

An option with ugly `while` loop :

```
xx <- c(3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L)
#Initialise output vector
yy <- integer(length(xx))
#Assign the 1st group
yy[1:xx[1]] <- 1
#Set the current position
i <- xx[1] + 1
#Initialise the group number
group <- 2

#While all the groups have been assigned
while(any(yy == 0)) {
  #Assign the next group number
  yy[i:(i+xx[i] - 1)] <- group
  #Increment the group number
  group <- group + 1
  #Increment the current position.
  i <- i+xx[i]
}
yy

#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible way using Rcpp:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("
IntegerVector decode_rle(IntegerVector x) {
    const int n = x.size();
    IntegerVector res(n);
    int cnt = 0;
    int rle = x[0];
    int gcnt = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        cnt++;
        if(cnt <= rle){
            res[i] = gcnt;
        }else{
            rle = x[i];
            cnt = 1;
            res[i] = ++gcnt;
        }
    }
    return res;
}")

xx <- c(3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1)
decode_rle(xx)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 6
```

Comment: Great solution. I've been meaning to start learning c++ soon as there have been numerous suggestions that it would help improve my grasp on programming in general.

Answer (score 1):

Taking clues from @GKi's fabulous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66758687/2884859), I have translated it to `purrr::accumulate`

```
accumulate(seq_len(length(xx)-1), .init = xx[1], ~ifelse(.x > .y, .x, .x + xx[.x +1]))

[1]  3  3  3  7  7  7  7  8 10 10 12 12 16 16 16 16
```

Answer (score 1):

Although not what you were looking for in the first place, I finally found a way to get to the desired output through `recursion` which is one of my favorite programming techniques. I also tried to be as concise as possible in my approach. Hope you like it:

```
xx <- c(3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L)

i <- 1
out <- c()
fn <- function(x) {
  out <<- c(out, rep(i, x[1]))
  x <- x[-(1:x[1])]
  if(length(x) != 0) {
    i <<- i + 1
  } else {
    return(out)
  }
  fn(x)
}

fn(xx)
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 6
```